# How to disable the page and display a In process text Or a Loading in Asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, loading, pageload

I call a method to Send Email to the user ID and Redirect to the same page. Since the time taken for the server to send email is high, the page appears as if the send button is not clicked. Since there are no response from the website. I want to display a loading image or something, to show that the server is processing the request. How can I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not to familair with the UpdateProgress myself, but have seen it used before.

You need to have an animated gif, and the update progress will show this whenever the page is busy.

```
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div class="">
                    Processing Please Wait...
                    <img runat="server" id="ajaxLoader" src="~/images/loadinfo.net.gif" alt="loading" /></div>
                <div class="" style="height: 10px;">
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

With regards to actually disabling the page, this I dont think can be done.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `UpdateProgress` control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821.aspx

(Or even better: send the e-mail asynchronous in the background)

Answer (score 3):

You can use either with an UpdateProgress control (as covered in the other answers), or a simple piece of jQuery.

**jQuery example:**

```
$('#my-button-id'').click(function(){
   $('#my-button-id').hide();
   $('#my-loading-image-id').show();
});
```

Remember to reenable the button if the action does not complete properly, else the user will not be able to try again.